# Handheld stylesheet not used on my HTC

Tags: css, mobile, stylesheet, handheld

I'm using

```
<link href="stylesheets/mobile.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="handheld" />
```

To include an alternate stylesheet for mobile devices. But it seems that the stylesheet is not being loaded at all on my HTC. Why is this? And more importantly, how do I make sure my mobile stylesheet is loaded on all handhelds?

You can view the live website here: [www.webvalid.nl/thomas](http://www.webvalid.nl/thomas)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend using the CSS3 `@media screen and (max-width: ###px)` media queries as documented nicely at http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/css3-media-queries

All HTC (Android ones, anyway) and iPhone browsers support this, as far as I know, due to their good CSS3 support.